# How to count digits of given number?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, numbers

I want the user to enter a number and print back the amount of digits of that number.

I know that I can use `length`, but my homework asking for `while` loop.

This is what I have so far:

```js
var num;
var count = 0;

num = prompt('Enter number: ');

function counter(x, y) {
  while (x > 0) {
    y++;
    x /= 10;
  }
  return y;
}

var result = counter(num, count);

console.log(result);
```

When I give the number `3456` (example), I get back the number `328`. I want it to print back the number `4`.

Comment: convert the number to string and access the `.length` property

Comment: @nickzoum well that's one way to do it

Comment: move the `count` variable in and make it `let` block scoped

Comment: You need to convert the input to int because when you get the input it is in string type `num = int(prompt('Enter number: '));`

Comment: Argh. Homeworks just keep getting further and further away from how real applications are supposed to work.

Comment: Should `0` return `0` or `1`?

Comment: @EricWu When you learn a musical instrument, you are told to play scales and arpeggios, not because they are pleasant to hear, but because they teach you technique. Coding exercises are often similar: simplified and constrained, so that you learn ways to think about algorithms and program design. Often, there can be a whole sequence of "now do it without this built-in".

Comment: Let's also mention the mathematical way to do this without a loop and without treating it as a string. That's taking the integral part of the 10-based logarithm and adding 1. `Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(num))) + 1` Taking the absolute value makes it also work with negative numbers. 0 is a special case.

Comment: Please don't do it this way! It is very inefficient. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the division operation will eventually end up converting `x` to a float and you'll have something like:

```
x / 10 === 0.1;
x / 10 === 0.01;
x / 10 === 0.001;
....
```

if you always parse (round) the result of the division to an integer, you'll get the expected result.

```js
var num;
var count = 0;

num = prompt('Enter number: ');

function counter(x, y) {
  while (x > 0) {
    y++;
    x = parseInt(x / 10);
  }
  return y;
}

var result = counter(num, count);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Using `parseInt` on numbers is wrong... "parse" means parse something out of strings.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
x /= 10;
```

Should be changed to:

```
x = Math.floor(x / 10);
```

The logic assumes integer division: 1234 is supposed to become 123, 12, 1 and 0.  JavaScript does not have built in integer division so you need to use `Math.floor` to emulate it. Complete example with some fixes:

```js
function countDigits(num) {
  var count = 0;
  while (num > 0) {
    num = Math.floor(num / 10);
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}

var num;
do {
  num = Number(prompt("Enter number:"));
} while (Number.isNaN(num));
num = Math.abs(num); // just in case you want to handle -ve numbers
var result = countDigits(num);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should convert the input into a number, preferably using the `Number` function (using unary `+` has the same effect).

Secondly a division like `5 / 10` will return `0.5` which is bigger than `0`. You should instead check if the number is bigger than or equal to `1`.

```js
function counter(num) {
  num = Math.abs(num) / 10;
  var count = 1;  
  while (num >= 1) {
    count++;
    num /= 10;
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(counter(+prompt('Enter number: ')));
```

You could also use a `do while` loop and avoid having an extra division outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, `y` doesn't need to be a parameter, it can be a local variable. But that's not your problem; let's add some extra logging to your loop:

```js
function counter(x) {
  let y=0;
  while (x > 0) {
    console.log("x=" + x + ", y=" + y);
    y++;
    x /= 10;
  }
  return y;
}
counter(3456);
```

The output looks like this:

```
x=3456, y=0
x=345.6, y=1
x=34.56, y=2
x=3.4560000000000004, y=3
x=0.3456, y=4
x=0.03456, y=5
...
```

You wanted the loop to stop at `0.3456`, but that's still more than `0`. (This mistake actually gives you a chance to learn something extra: can you explain why the loop ever finishes at all?)

Hopefully this will give you enough of a hint to complete the homework assignment - remember that debugging is an *extremely* important part of programming.

Answer (score 1):

You could check againt a number by taking the power of a decimal count.

```js
function counter(value) {
    var decimals = 0;
    do {
        decimals++;
    } while (value >= 10 ** decimals)
    return decimals;
}

console.log(counter(0));
console.log(counter(1));
console.log(counter(7));
console.log(counter(42));
console.log(counter(999));
console.log(counter(1000));
console.log(counter(1001));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please don't use cycles to measure length of an integer...**

Use *math* instead! Logarithm will do much better job for you.

```
function numberLength(number) {
    return Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(number))) + 1
}

console.log(numberLength(YOUR_NUMBER));
```

This code returns `NaN` when the input is `0`. I think it depends on your philosophy what length the `0` should have, so I am leaving that case unhandled.

Comment: It is a homework assignment related to JavaScript and specifically asks to use a loop, not Math.

Comment: @Salman A I know, but there will be other people reading this when doing different homework, and search engine might lead them to this question. So they should be able to find a better solution here. :-)

Comment: it's better to use `Math.floor` rather than `parseInt` for numeric arguments

Comment: @georg Thanks! I actually don't know anything about JavaScript, haha :D

Comment: This is a **coding exercise**. If you think the question should make that clearer, then propose an edit to the question, but since it already says "I know that I can use `length`, but my homework asking for `while` loop" this is simply **an incorrect answer** to the question as asked.